# Add a cooldown to a Shooting Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I Have this simple scrip fot the player to shoot a prefab when clicking the "Disparo" button, in this case the left click. Now its broken because you can spam the click and shoot every second. I dont Know how to add a cooldown to this to make that you only can shoot every certain time.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class ProjectileShooter : MonoBehaviour
{
public AudioClip disparo;
GameObject prefab;
public float shootSpeed;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    prefab = Resources.Load("Projectile") as GameObject;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Disparo"))
    {
        GameObject Projectile = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
        Projectile.transform.position = transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 2;
        Rigidbody rb = Projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.velocity = Camera.main.transform.forward * shootSpeed;
        Destroy(Projectile, 2.2f);


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want is to set a boolean to check if the process is in cooldown.

```
private bool isInCooldown = false;
```

Then in your if statement you can **invoke** a new method, after completing your computations. As explained in Unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) Invoke method:

> Invokes the method methodName in time seconds.

```
if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Disparo"))
{
    if(!isInCooldown){
       //Your code here

       Invoke("ResetCooldown", 2f);
       isInCooldown = true;
    }
}
```

And the ResetCooldown method is simply:

```
private void ResetCooldown () {
    isInCooldown = false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The script below sets the cool time easily. You can set the cooldown time by changing **shootcoolTime**. and do not touch **youCanShootNow**. that variable only use to save time when you can shoot again;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class ProjectileShooter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip disparo;
    GameObject prefab;
    public float shootSpeed;
    public float shootcoolTime;

    float youCanShootNow;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        prefab = Resources.Load("Projectile") as GameObject;
        youCanShootNow = 0;
    }


    public void Update()
    {
        if (youCanShootNow < Time.time)
        {
            if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Disparo"))
            {
                GameObject Projectile = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
                Projectile.transform.position = transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 2;
                Rigidbody rb = Projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                rb.velocity = Camera.main.transform.forward * shootSpeed;
                Destroy(Projectile, 2.2f);
                youCanShootNow = Time.time + coolTime;

            }

        }
    }
}
```